Why isn't jquery inner html not changing in this context?
I'm adding new content display by getting an html snippet from the server and applying some changes in it. However I can't change the jquery object created and I don't understand why. I've seen lots of similar questions to mine but I don't think they apply to my case.
The html returned from this GET request is in this format:
<div>
 <!-- more content-->
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <span class="post-conteudo">SOME TEXT I WANT TO CHANGE</span>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>

My code is:
$.get( `/myUrl`, function( data ) {
 if(data){
   internalContent = $($(data).find('.post-conteudo')[0]).html();
   treatedContent = applyChanges(internalContent);
                
   $($(data).find('.post-conteudo')[0]).html(treatedContent)

   localStorage.setItem(`data-post-${idPostCitado}`, data);
                
 }
});

When debugging I see that internalContent is equal to SOME TEXT I WANT TO CHANGE so I assume I'm correctly referencing the internal element. But when I try to change it, it does,'t change and data remains as before.

Unrelated to your question: Why do you use jQuery with the deprecated callback API instead of fetch with the modern promise API?

I didn't see anything about this being deprecated in the official documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

The callback API is deprecated/outdated. 8 years ago this pattern was replaced with promises. I don't mean this specific function or library. jQuery was designed and developed long ago, before promises were implemented in JavaScript.

$(data) creates a jQuery instance, but it doesn't manipulate data.
You can do it this way:
data = $(data);
data.find('.post-conteudo').eq(0).html(treatedContent);
data = data.html();


you solution answered very well, I only had to modify it to data = data.prop('outerHTML');in order to also get whole html content into data

The issue lies in how you're trying to manipulate the HTML content within data. Here's the core problem:
When you retrieve data from the server in the $.get callback, it is a string containing HTML, not an actual DOM element. Therefore, jQuery operations like $(data).find('.post-conteudo') work on a temporary, detached jQuery object, not the original data. Any changes you make to this jQuery object do not affect the original string data.
To work with the HTML as a manipulatable structure, parse it into a DOM-like format using jQuery or native DOM methods. Here's how you can fix your code:
$.get(`/myUrl`, function(data) {
    if (data) {
        let parsedData = $($.parseHTML(data));
        let internalContent = parsedData.find('.post-conteudo').html();
        let treatedContent = applyChanges(internalContent);
        parsedData.find('.post-conteudo').html(treatedContent);
        let updatedData = parsedData.prop('outerHTML');
        localStorage.setItem(`data-post-${idPostCitado}`, updatedData);
    }
});

